# PHP image upload and store the image name to MySQL table column script not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

The script is constructed like this:

```
// Function For Image Upload
public function storeUploadedImage($image) {
    if ($image['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // Does the Document object have an ID?
        if (is_null($this->id))
            trigger_error("Document::storeUploadedImage(): Attempt to upload an image for an Document object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR);
        // Delete any previous image(s) for this Document
        $this->deleteImages();
        // Get and store the image filename extension
        $this->imgExtension = strtolower(strrchr($image['name'], '.'));
        // Store the image
        $tempFilename = trim($image['tmp_name']); 
        if (is_uploaded_file ($tempFilename)) {
        if (!(move_uploaded_file($tempFilename, $this->getImagePath())))
            trigger_error("Document::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR);
        if (!(chmod($this->getImagePath(), 0666)))
            trigger_error("Document::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR);}
        // Get the image size and type/Extension
        $attrs = getimagesize ($this->getImagePath());
        $imageWidth = $attrs[0];
        $imageHeight = $attrs[1];
        $imageType = $attrs[2];
        // Load the image into memory
        switch ($imageType) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $imageResource = imagecreatefromgif ($this->getImagePath());
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg ($this->getImagePath());
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $imageResource = imagecreatefrompng ($this->getImagePath());
            break;
        default:
            trigger_error ("Document::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        // Copy And Resize The Image To Create The Thumbnail
        $thumbHeight = intval ($imageHeight / $imageWidth * 120);
        $thumbResource = imagecreatetruecolor (120, $thumbHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($thumbResource, $imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, $thumbHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
        // Save the Image thumbnail
        switch ($imageType) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif ($thumbResource, $this->getImagePath("thumb"));
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg ($thumbResource, $this->getImagePath("thumb"), 85);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng ($thumbResource, $this->getImagePath("thumb"));
            break;
        default:
            trigger_error ("Document::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        $this->update();
    }
}
// Funcion To Get The Relative Path To The Article's Fullsize Image
public function getImagePath($type="fullsize") {
    return ($this->id && $this->imgExtension) ? ("/images" . "/$type/" . $this->id . $this->imgExtension) : false;
}
```

This is the form input field:

```
 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" placeholder="Choose an image to upload" maxlength="255"/>
```

The rest of the inputs store to the MySQL database table. No error is showing for the upload. The image isn't uploading to the designated directory which is defined in a configuration file which is required in this script

Comment: does your form have attr enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? FWIW, I use an open source gallery app for this. I think the one I use is no longer supported, but I'm sure that there must be dozens of alternatives.

Comment: Please indent properly your code

Comment: @Thi Tran I did have that attr setup like that.

Comment: @Cliff Burton I'm sorry about that. I've been working with PHP like this since the beginning. I know most aren't used to it but it's been more easier for me to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't post comments yet, so I'm writing this as an answer.

You check whether image was uploaded correctly and work with it, but the function does nothing otherwise. Then you check if file was uploaded properly with `is_uploaded_file` and if it wasn't... you continue your routine. It would be wiser to throw an exception, like you're doing in other places.

Do you have error reporting level set on reasonable level (so you would know what's going wrong)?

Comment: The script stores the image name with extension as it's supposed to do "example.jpg" in the column of the table but the image isn't being stored in the directories.

Comment: I suggest you to add `else` statements to `if`s I mentioned, then test the script one more time.

Comment: I error reporting set to all. If you have any suggestions to change script where it will work right let me see how it works.

Comment: You should add those `else` statements I suggested, to see what (if anything there) is going wrong.

Comment: I tried running else statements within the trigger_error() portion of the scripts yet I didn't get back anything. I'm still not understanding where this fails on the upload of the image.

Comment: Could you `echo` some text in the beginning of every `if` and `else` block, so you could track which blocks of code are being executed?